# In MySQL, ' results in error, ` works fine. why?

Tags: sql, mysql, quotes

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'admin'";#works

$query = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = 'admin'";#does not work
```

Is this yet another quirk Im going to have to get used to, or is something funny going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Single quotes (`'`) and double quotes (`"`) are used to specify strings in MySQL. Backticks (`` ` ``) are used for column/table references.

Your second query will fail for two reasons:

1. `'users'` specifies a string, not a reference to the table `users`, and `FROM` expects a [table reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html#id3146346).
2. `'username' = 'admin'` does a string comparison, and the string `username` is never equal to the string `admin`.

Comment: +1: SQL in general considers anything inside single quotes to be text, not a column name.  MySQL uses backticks (no others to my knowledge), but they're [only necessary to escape the times when someone made the poor decision to use what is a reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: If you enable ANSI mode, then the standard double quotes are accepted as well for column and table names (making MySQL more compliant with the SQL standard - in fact there are a bunch of options that should be turned on to disable some of the non-standard MySQL quirks)

Answer (score 0):

It's not legal syntax to quote the name of a column with '

The ` (backtick) is used to quote identifiers.

Since none of your columns are reserved keywords, this would work too:

```
 "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'admin'"
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, by default single-quotes (`'`) and double-quotes (`"`) are literal string delimiters, while backticks (`` ` ``) are identifier quotes. If you set the SQL mode to include ANSI_QUOTES, then double-quotes will also be identifier quotes rather than literal string delimiters.